# Codeigniter call function in nested extends controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

I have a `MY_Controller` php file with `MY_Controller` class and `Other_Controller` that extends `My_Controller` class in my `application/core` folder.

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function SomeMethod()
    {
        echo "method MY_Controller";
    }
}
class Other_Controller extends My_Controller 
{
    function __construct()
    {
       parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

On my `Application/controller` folder :

```
    Class Main extends Other_Controller
    { include(APPPATH.'core/Other_Controller.php');
        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            // Call SomeMethod function name?
        }
    }
```

Can I call SomeMethod function from `MY_Controller` to Main Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, simply use [`parent`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) keyword same way as you're using it with constructor:

```
class Main extends Other_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        parent::SomeMethod(); // echoes "method MY_Controller"
    }
}
```

In case `Other_Controller` class overrides `MY_Controller::SomeMethod`, you still can call the original `SomeMethod` from the `Main` class by using full class name and [scope resolution operator `::`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php):

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function SomeMethod()
    {
        echo "method MY_Controller";
    }
}

class Other_Controller extends My_Controller 
{
    function __construct()
    {
       parent::__construct();
    }

    function SomeMethod()
    {
        echo "method Other_Controller";
    }
}

class Main extends Other_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        parent::SomeMethod(); // echoes "method Other_Controller"
        MY_Controller::SomeMethod(); // echoes "method MY_Controller"
    }
}
```

Comment: how to change MY_Controller::SomeMethod(); calling method to "$this->" method calling?

Comment: You don't need to change it to `$this->SomeMethod()`, because `SomeMethod` actually don't belong to `$this` class

Comment: Just FYI, `MY_Controller::SomeMethod()` works both for static and non-static methods

Comment: anyway, I just wanna know, could MY_Controller::SomeMethod() calling method be change to MY_Controller -> SomeMethod() ? thank you

Comment: 1. If there is no overriding of `SomeMethod` in `Other_Controller` class, you can use `$this->SomeMethod()` - it will work just fine.


2. If `SomeMethod` is overridden, then `MY_Controller::SomeMethod()` is your best option. Unfortunately, you can't use `MY_Controller -> SomeMethod()`

Comment: Please, take a look at this example https://3v4l.org/TrMLu
You can change and eval it to test the answer